# call python function inside shell in pycharm

Tags: scripts, python, pycharm

I am using python 2.7 and Pycharm 2017.3.3, and I have installed the shell plugin for Pycharm.

There is a shell script that when I run it in terminal it works properly, but when I want to run it inside the Pycharm there is a SyntaxError.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

python ./script/experiment/train_deepmar_resnet50.py \
    --sys_device_ids="(0,)" \
    --dataset=rap \
    .
    .
    .
    --model_weight_file= \
```

The error is as follows

```
/home/socialab/anaconda2/bin/python2.7 /home/socialab/Desktop/Implementation001/Proj/script/experiment/train.sh
  File "/home/socialab/Desktop/Implementation001/Proj/script/experiment/train.sh", line 3
    python <train_deepmar_resnet50>.py \
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Do you have any idea why it does not run in Pycharm?

Comment: A file with shebang `/usr/bin/env python` will usually be executed by python and not the shell. That's not a shell script.

Comment: Hi! Are you trying to execute `python` in Python? Please explain what are you trying to do. You have obviously some Python code and shell script file (`train.sh`) but the rest is mystery to me.